# C#, Windows Forms, TextBox для int, double и т.д

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, что бы ввести текст и сохранить его в переменную типа *string* можно использовать *TextBox*, а если мне надо ввести и сохранить числовые значения *int* или *double*, как быть?

Существует ли свой *TextBox* для цифровых значений? (*int*, *double* и т.д.).
Одним из вариантов использования *TextBox* для *int* или *double* является использовать *Convert.ToDouble*.

**Вопрос заключается в том**, существует ли свой *TextBox* для *int* и *double* или надо использовать *TextBox* + *Convert.ToDouble* ?

Так же еще вопрос, при вводе значения *double*, если я допустим ставлю точку, за место запятой, выскакивает ошибка, тут надо создавать метод который будет обрабатывать сначала *string*, заменяя все точки запятыми и удаляя пробелы, и только потом конвертировать или существует встроенный метод?

Comment: Для правильной обработки точек/запятых используйте [правильную локаль](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Можно создать свой контрол **NumericTextBox**, который будет принимать только цифры и возвращать int через свойство **IntValue** а double через **DecimalValue** как описано здесь http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: А зачем создвавать свой, если есть готовый [NumericUpDown][1]?


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, Вы можете через DataBindings привязать свойство Text к свойству объекта через BindingSource, которое имеет числовой тип. При этом, если пользователь ввёл некорректное значение, он не сможет снять фокус до тех пор, пока не введёт корректное.

Answer (score 0):

Для замены символов в строке используй [String.Replace - метод (Char, Char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/czx8s9ts.aspx)
А потом конвертируй строку в double

```
void ConvertToDoubleFromTextBox()
    {
        try
        {
            var p = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text.Replace(',', '.'));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: костыль. Не делайте так